# CSS Problem: Replacement for z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

Is there any replacement for z-index?

My code is too long, thus I will briefly explain my code in text form:

My website layout is (from top to bottom):

- Banner
- Menu Bar
- Content
- Footer

In 1 of the menus, I added a SlideDown (using jquery) effect when rollover to display to submenus.

I have 5 images, right below the menu bar, => `<div id='images'>`. Each image under `<li class="thumb">`

My problem: When I roll over the menu, the submenus are behind the images. I tried all methods, debug with firebu, tested on all popular browsers, IE,FF,Chrome,Opera and Safari, none of them works. I set z-index and position: relative / absolute, but no luck.

Is there any others way to display my submenus in front of the images?

Please help

EDIT:

Hi Guys,

I fixed the problem. But its weird, and I dont understand why.

the initial css of submenu:

```
#submenu{
  ...
  z-index: 500;
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

After I change the z-index value to 1000, it works now. I dont understand why though. The z-index for the image is -100, before and after I fixed the problems. Is there any specific reason why the value 500 does not work, while 1000 can work? I didnt use z-index on others elements(rest of the page). (Maybe I should open a new question for this). Anyway, sorry for posting this useless question here, any kind-heart soul, could you please close this thread/question?

Comment: An example would help a lot, can't you link to the code?

Comment: could u post link to your page.

Comment: I am sorry, I have an agreement with my client, not to publish the site until its fully.. no bugs(very hard).. developed. I try to post some codes here once I get the permission. I am really sorry about that.

Comment: it should work fine in any browser (well maybe have some problems with old versions of ie), but i know that there's a problem when using flash and z-index... but if that's not the case maybe you have something wrong in your css code (perhaps a typo) and the browsers are not reading the z-index or something else migth be wrong.. we do need the code, at least use jsfiddle.net to publish an exemple

Comment: Yeah, we’re going to need to see at least some code. If you could post just the HTML and CSS for the menu bar and `<div id="images">`, that should help. As far as your client goes, just don’t tell them. With the greatest possible respect, I don’t think you’ll have developed any code that the rest of the world is desperate to steal.

Comment: Haha, indeed Paul. My codes are very standard. But, you know, IT-illiterate clients are kinda troublesome sometimes, they even ask me to develop a "disable view source-code"(html) feature but not in flash, and I was like "what the hell!!". Well, I just dont want to get sue, or pay money, you know. lols

Comment: @webdev_007 you can delete your own question, as long as it doesn't have any upvoted answers, I believe. --- Look for the `delete` link below the list of tags when viewing your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell how you've laid out your page but here's a suggestion.

Try the following:

```
<div id="banner"><!--banner contents--></div>
<div id="menu"><!--menu contents--></div>
<div id="content"><!--main contents--></div>
<div id="footer"><!--footer contents--></div>
```

Then in css you want:

```
div#menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I don't like to use this many div's when making a website, but its the easiest way of getting my message across. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi differsworld. I fixed the bug and I will post my solution in my edited question. Thanks for the answer anyway